# Catch and handle the ZeroDivisionError - python

Tags: python

```
def divide(divisor, dividend):
  if divisor is not 0:
    return dividend / divisor
  else:
    return 'Division by zero not allowed'
assert divide(0,10) == "Division by zero not allowed"
```

Is this a suitable method to divide by zero and get a result - (division by zero not allowed)? Or is there an easier way to reach a solution?

When running this code, I get the error Assertion Error:
but the error is not defined/ specified.
What have I done wrong in this code and how do I fix it!

Comment: Don't use `is` and `is not` to compare numbers. Use `==` and `!=`.

Comment: You can only write `if divisor:` which will be stated as False if it is 0 or 0.0

Comment: @MisterNox How would I write the code using this?

Comment: Simply instead of `if divisor is not 0:` you can use `if divisor:`.

Answer (score 1):

For me your code works perfectly. However you can also use `try` to catch errors. Here is my suggestion:

```
def divide(divisor, dividend):
    try:
        return divisor / dividend
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "Division by zero not allowed"
print(divide(10, 0))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I have tried this and I still get the same error - AssertionError. However I have tried it on an online python editor and it worked. Do you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: My questions are:
- What python are you using?
- Is this the whole code?
But maybe this site will help: https://airbrake.io/blog/python-exception-handling/python-assertionerror

Comment: I am using google drive and this is the whole code.